# how to add custom column when exporting excel in DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatable

Hey everyone I want to add a Custom column that doesn't exit in table, but I want to add a column when exporting it in Excel.

I will try to achieve it using header function of DataTable Export option.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#example").DataTable({
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: "excelHtml5",
        exportOptions: {
          //   trim: false,
          //   stripHtml: false,
          format: {
            header: function (html, index, node) {
              //   return index + " [" + html + "]";
              console.log(typeof index);
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

How can I add another Column to the table when exporting?

Comment: Simplest solution: Create your extra column as a regular DataTables column. Set it to be [hidden](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible). That way, it is available to be exported. There are other approaches, but they are more complicated.